# Dots in bracket to access nested property

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-table

Consider the object below:

```
var item = {
  id: 'some-id',
  price: 12,
  customer: {
     id: 'fake-id',
     name: 'fake-name'
   }
};
```

We can access the customer name using "dots" or "brackets" as below:

- `item.customer.name`
- `item['customer'].name`
- `item.customer['name']`
- `item.['customer']['name']`

**Question**

In Javascript or Typescript, is there a way to access customer name like the following?

`item['customer.name']` or `item[customer.name]`

**Notes**

In angular I created a reusable table component based on the mat-table, which includes pagination, sort filter and bunch of other functions... I use the following for the column definitions:

*mytable.component.ts:*

```
export interface MyTableCol {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    // some other settings...
}
```

*mypage.component.ts:*

```
cols: MyTableCol[] = [
  {id: 'price', title: 'Total Price'},
  {id: 'customer.name', title: 'Customer Name' }
];
```

*mypage.component.html:*

```
<my-table [columns]="cols"></my-table>
```

*mytable.component.html:*

```
<ng-container [matColumnDef]="col.id" *ngFor="let col of columns">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
            {{ col.title}}
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        {{ element[col.id] }}
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

However, for the nested properties (customer.name) this won't work. I think the reason is the line: `element[col.id]` converts to `element['customer.id']` in case of the customer name column.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Looks related? [accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key)

Comment: you can't do item['customer']['name'] ?
or do you mean like element[col.id.split('.')[0]][col.id.split('.')[1]] ? 
kinda confused about the issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work automatically to pass a string like that to access the properties, you need to create a getter function like [lodash _get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get) and use it to find the value you need. And then write something like:

```
{{ _getAtr(element, col.id) }}
```